# PHPUnit Skeleton Generator not running boostrap file

Tags: php, phpunit

I am running the following command to generate tests

```
php "phpunit-skelgen.phar" generate-test 
  --bootstrap "/path/to/autoload.php" MyCoolClass "/path/to/CoolClass.php"
```

or this somewhat arbitrary variation

```
php "phpunit-skelgen.phar" generate-test 
  --bootstrap="/path/to/autoload.php" MyCoolClass "/path/to/CoolClass.php"
```

Where autoload.php is as follows

```
<?php
  // autoload.php
  require_once('/path/to/BaseCoolClass.php');
?>
```

This results in the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'BaseCoolClass' not found in /path/to/CoolClass.php on line 8
```

However, if I prefix CoolClass.php with `require_once('/path/to/BaseCoolClass.php');` there is no problem; it seems like `autoload.php` is not being included.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was that `--bootstrap "/path/to/autoload.php"` included the quotation marks in the file name. The fix is to remove the quotation marks.